# ion-side-menu, can we set 'side' property from scope?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-side-menu side="{{menuSide}}">
```

I want to show menu from left side for English, and to be on right side for Arabic content.

And set menuSide from controller like,

```
 $scope.menuSide = 'left'; //for English and 'right' for arabic
```

How I toggle the side menu is from controller with following code,

```
 $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();// for English
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();//for Arabic
```

but how it render on browser is

```
<ion-side-menu side="right" is-enabled="true" width="275" class="menu menu-{{menuSide}}" style="width: 275px; z-index: 0;">
```

Comment: what is actually goes wrong? I just test it `<ion-side-menu side="right">
  </ion-side-menu>` will enable right to left menu and `<ion-side-menu side="left">
  </ion-side-menu>` will enable left to right menu. Of course you can set the left or right menu with `$scope.menuSide`. You dont have to use `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();` actually. If things harder to you, try to use `ng-if`

Comment: ng-if is fine, but trying to avoid code-repeat, I cannot set the 'side' from scope

Comment: try `$rootScope.menuSide` ..remember to define `$rootScope` in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug. It is properly putting the value into the side attribute, but looks like the directive grabs the value before it is bound. As you mentioned, it rendered as following:

```
<ion-side-menu side="right" is-enabled="true" width="275" class="menu menu-{{menuSide}}" style="width: 275px;">
```

Looks like this may be a bug. You could try filing a bug on GitHub and see what the guys say.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic framework have not implemented this, check the ionic forum http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-side-menu-can-we-set-side-property-from-scope/16494 ,

this feature might be great to support for rtl language like Arabic.